# Numbering equations while also using flushleft

Tags: horizontal-alignment, numbering, amsmath, mathtools

I want an equation to be flushed to the left but I want it to be numbered as well.

When I use this code it is flushed to the left but does not number my equation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
      \begin{flushleft}
$\ \textnormal{(ii) \ minimise \ $p$ \ subject \ to } \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  f(x_k) + \nabla f(x_k)^Tp + \frac{1}{2}p^T\nabla{^2}f(x_k)p\\
            \| \ {p} \| \le \Delta _k\\
                  \end{array}
              \right.
  \ $
      \end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

When I use this code it is numbered but not flushed to the left:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{bbold}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}



     \begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
      \begin{equation}
      \ \textnormal{(ii) \ minimise \ $p$ \ subject \ to } \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  f(x_k) + \nabla f(x_k)^Tp + \frac{1}{2}p^T\nabla{^2}f(x_k)p\\
            \| \ {p} \| \le \Delta _k\\
                  \end{array}
              \right.
  \ 
      \end{equation}
      \end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how can I have both a numbered equation and for it to be flushed to the left? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \textnormal{(ii) minimise $p$ subject to } \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      f(x_k) + \nabla f(x_k)^T p + \frac{1}{2} p^T \nabla^2 f(x_k) p \\
      \| p \| \leq \Delta_k
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{flushleft}
  $\textnormal{(ii) minimise $p$ subject to } \left\{
      \begin{array}{ll}
        f(x_k) + \nabla f(x_k)^T p + \frac{1}{2} p^T \nabla^2 f(x_k) p \\
        \| p \| \leq \Delta_k
      \end{array}
    \right.
  $
\end{flushleft}

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{flushleft}
  $\textnormal{(ii) minimise $p$ subject to } \left\{
      \begin{array}{ @{} l }
        f(x_k) + \nabla f(x_k)^T p + \frac{1}{2} p^T \nabla^2 f(x_k) p \\
        \| p \| \leq \Delta_k
      \end{array}
    \right.
  $
  \hfill
  \refstepcounter{equation}\mbox{(\theequation)}
\end{flushleft}

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),align=left,leftmargin=*]
  \item Some regular item

  \item minimise $p$ subject to $\begin{cases}
        f(x_k) + \nabla f(x_k)^T p + \frac{1}{2} p^T \nabla^2 f(x_k) p \\
        \| p \| \leq \Delta_k
      \end{cases}$
    \hfill
  \refstepcounter{equation}\mbox{(\theequation)}

  \item Another regular item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Suggestions include:

- Using `cases` instead of `\left\{ <array> \right.`;
- Using a list (`enumerate`) instead of setting `(ii)` manually;
- Adding an equation number via

  ```
  \hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\mbox{(\theequation)}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

For displayed equations, you can use the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`. The equation indent is an optional argument. B.t.w., needless to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`. Also, you can simplify the code using the `cases` environment in the place of `array`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation}
    \ \textnormal{(ii) \ minimise \ $p$ \ subject \ to }
    \begin{cases}
      f(x_k) + ∇ f(x_k)^Tp + \frac{1}{2}p^T∇{²}f(x_k)p \\
      \| \ {p} \|  ≤ Δ_k                                   \\
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

\begin{fleqn}
  \begin{equation}
    \ \textnormal{(ii) \ minimise \ $p$ \ subject \ to }
    \begin{cases}
      f(x_k) + ∇ f(x_k)^Tp + \frac{1}{2}p^T∇{²}f(x_k)p \\
      \| \ {p} \|  ≤ Δ_k                                   \\
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
  \begin{equation}
    \ \textnormal{(ii) \ minimise \ $p$ \ subject \ to }
    \begin{cases}
      f(x_k) + ∇ f(x_k)^Tp + \frac{1}{2}p^T∇{²}f(x_k)p \\
      \| \ {p} \|  ≤ Δ_k                                   \\
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `fleqn` is defined in `amsmath`, isn't it?

Comment: It's an option of `amsmath` (for all equations) and an *environment* of `nccmath` (which builds upon amsmath) (for particular equations).

Comment: Thank you for information. I'm not very familiar with `nccmath` ...

Comment: It's especially useful for its `medium-size` commands and environments, when `textstyle` is too small and `\displaystyle too large.